# What can cause an unexpected reboot during setup?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, setup-deployment

I have built a web setup project in Visual Studio. When it is installed on one machine it prompted the user to reboot and I don't know why.

It is installing over the top of a previous version. It doesn't do it on my machine.

What can cause this, and is there any way I can prevent it? I don't see any reason for it to occur, it's just a fairly standard ASP.NET site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the only cause of a reboot on .NET is that it is trying to overwrite something that is in use. It needs the reboot in order to remove the handle. For an ASP.NET site, try stopping IIS before the install, then re-starting it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

[HOW TO: Control System Restarts in a Setup Project That You Created by Using Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827020)